# Auto-Completion V Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

Intellisense seems to be failing in my Visual Studio 2008.

If I write "using System.c" then I get the suggestions such as Collections, etc.
But other than that it's not doing anything.

no key words detected, no class/variable detected, etc.

Tools-Options-Text Editor-All Languages-Statement Completion is checked on.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you start visual studio in safe mode (Devenv.exe /SafeMode)? Do you still see that problem?

Comment: you got it! it's working now. Any solution for making it work the normal way?

Comment: If you have plugins for VS, one of them is creating the problem. Disable/re-enable them one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: It's kind of a pretty fresh install with just the program itself, nothing extra. But will check the installation package. Thanks.

Comment: Done! just re opened the program again (after safe mode) and now the auto completion is working, Thank you a lot! Post it as an answer if you want and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Visual Studio in safemode (DevEnv.exe /SafeMode) and see if the problem persists. If it does, the most probable cause is a malfunctioning plugin/extension. Try then to disable/re-enable them one by one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my solution too. CTRL+ALT+SPACE will toggle between suggestion mode and completion mode.  CTRL+SPACE will pop up the menu (this may be a Resharper shortcut).  If that doesn't help try closing all your solutions, exiting Visual Studio completely, and reopen the solution.